# adding a function to php.ini

Tags: php

I used the function htmlentities() in my php script, but the server says: "undefined function"

After some searching, I understand that the php installation on my webhost does not include that function, and that I can add the function by changing the php.ini file, but I have spent many hours searching, and have not found any information on how to actually do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Who is your web host? Not all hosts allow you to modify the php.ini file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your webhost's PHP install doesn't have something so basic as `htmlentities()`, it's time to get a new webhost. If it's that bizarrely locked down, you're also not likely to be able to tweak `php.ini`...

Comment: i could even understand locked down, but missing such a simple function is just plain bizarre! +1 for new webhost! 8)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in the [manual](http://php.net/htmlentities) that says this function is in an optional module that you'd have enable - you just need PHP 4 or 5. Are you sure you're calling the right function?

Comment: It could be disabled via `php.ini`'s `disable_functions` setting, but why is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising that this would be unavailable, but have you tried the alternate htmlspecialchars? It will deal with the ones that are most important to deal with.